# A question combining generarized integral and limits

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

After summarizing a few examples, I induce a guess:

$f(x)>0$ is a continuous function in $[0, +\infty)$, $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)}$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{\lambda\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^{\lambda}f(x)\mathrm{d}x=+\infty$.

I believe it is correct, but I have no idea how to prove it. Thanks a lot if you can provide a valid proof or some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\lambda >0$. Then by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

\begin{align}
\lambda &= \int_0^\lambda 1 dx = \int_0^\lambda \sqrt{f(x)}\frac{1}{\sqrt {f(x)}} dx \\
&\le  \sqrt{ \int_0^\lambda f(x) dx} \sqrt{\int_0^\lambda \frac{1}{f(x) } dx}\\
\Rightarrow &\lambda ^2 \le  \int_0^\lambda f(x) dx \int_0^\lambda \frac{1}{f(x) } dx
\end{align}
Thus

$$\tag{1} \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_0^\lambda f(x) dx \ge \lambda \left( \int_0^\lambda \frac{1}{f(x) } dx\right)^{-1}.$$

Since

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{f(x)} dx$$
converges, it converges to some positive number. Hence the RHS of (1) goes to infinity as $\lambda \to +\infty$.